# macOS - How do I share files via Share Menu from command line?

Tags: sharing, macos

I want to automate file sharing via the system Share Menu 
and it would be very helpful to know how to do it from command line, 
like so:

- Activate Share Menu:

```bsh
share-with-share-menu /path/to/file
```

and a Share Menu appears on screen and let me choose which where to share the file to.

- Directly share to an app:

```bsh
share-with-share-menu /path/to/file --handler-id com.apple.mail
```

This opens up Mail.app (com.apple.mail) and compose a new email with the file attached.